# Laravel condition for secondary table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Mode `Position.php` has following code.

```
class Position extends \Eloquent {  


    public static function get_position_by_url($url) {

            return Position::where('url','=',$url)->where('status','=','0')->with('message')->get();
        }


        public function message() {
            return $this->hasMany('Message');
        }
    }
```

The above code works fine, What I need is to get data by condition in messages table, like following:

```
 class Position extends \Eloquent {        


        public static function get_position_by_url($url,$screenSize) {

                return Position::where('url','=',$url)->where('status','=','0')->with('message')->where('screensize','=',$screensize)->get();
            }


            public function message() {
                return $this->hasMany('Message');
            }
        }
```

But the both conditions are applied to positions table, which I want to apply second condition to messages table.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter eager loaded models by passing a closure:

```
return Position::where('url','=',$url)->where('status','=','0')->with(['message' => function($q) use ($screensize){
     $q->where('screensize','=',$screensize);
}])->get();
```

Like [documented here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) under *Eager Loading Constraints*